# Unix C-Shell: ?Need help for the this task

Tags: unix

i have given a task to make a C-shell script. I have list of ip address and device name respectively. For example;

```
cal 1 : 100.21.25.10
cal 2 : 100.21.25.11
cal 3 : 100.21.25.12
cal 4 : 100.21.25.14
and so on...
```

Based on this ip and device name, i need to rsh the ip address and get the disk free of the device.  The result of disk free will be save to a log. the details of the log will be have device name need to be housekeep. My idea is:

declared array :

```
set device =( cal1 cal2 cal3)
set ip = (100.21.25.10 100.21.25.11 100.21.25.12 100.21.25.14)
set highspace = 90

foreach data($ip)
set space = rsh $ip df -k

if (${space} >= ${highspace}) then   
echo "Please Housekeep $device:" >> $device.log
endif
```

is this gonna work? Or do you guys have better idea? Thanks.

Comment: Consider writing this script in *anything other than* C shell.  Also consider not using rsh; it's 2015.

Comment: the task need to using c-shell and rsh.

Comment: Is this gonna work?  Please try before you ask :)

Comment: Is this for a class? Who is teaching a class that requires using csh and rsh?

Comment: yeah..he give me old script that using c script and rsh..with a lot of ip address and want to summarize the script by using array.

Answer (score 1):

The C shell should [never be used anymore](http://www.shlomifish.org/open-source/anti/csh/).  Neither should `rsh`; we have `ssh` now.

Your task in Bourne shell:

```
#! /bin/sh

highspace=90
fs_to_watch=/path/to/filesystem/that/fills/up

exec 0<"$1"
while read cal calno colon addr; do
   space=$(ssh "$addr" df -k "$fs_to_watch" | 
           awk 'NR > 1 { sub(/%$/, "", $5); print $5 }')
   if [ "$space" -gt "$highspace" ]; then
       echo "Please Housekeep Cal-$calno"
   fi
done
```

Comment: im afraid i need to the script using c shell script.thanks

Comment: @wina No, you don't need a c-shell script. You have `/bin/sh` and `awk`.  And you *should* have `ssh`.  Use those instead.

Comment: set device =( cal1 cal2 cal3)
set ip = (100.21.25.10 100.21.25.11 100.21.25.12 100.21.25.14)
set highspace=90

the others same. but i have error:  syntax error at line 3: `(' unexpected

Comment: @wina I am not going to help you write a c-shell script.